# How to calculate sum in a 3D Array in java?

Tags: java

I want to calculate the total of each row of a multidimensional array I tried playing around with the loops I have initialized all the variables however im not sure how I should go about calculating the sum.;

```
//declaring array
    double calls [][][] = 
        {
                {{500,600,800},{700,800,900},{899,929,828},{292,900,727},{234,424,586},{997,734,876},{235,543,948}},
                {{112,223,893},{234,848,455},{454,929,435},{727,827,636},{334,828,929},{382,938,929},{233,456,346}},
                {{221,434,911},{374,647,338},{364,921,726},{919,823,221},{112,334,737},{912,261,562},{535,654,821}},
                {{233,838,912},{263,523,393},{737,373,928},{828,736,636},{325,324,876},{434,858,495},{239,458,959}}
        for(int weeks=0;weeks<4;weeks++) {
                    for(int callNum=0;callNum<7;callNum++) {
                        for(int dept=0;dept<3;dept++) {
                        counter+=(calls[weeks][callNum][dept]);
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int week=0;week<calls.length;week++) {
                for(int days=0;days<calls[week].length;days++) {
                    for(int resp=0;resp<calls[week][days].length;resp++) {
                        total=+counter;
                        counter++;

            }

                }
                System.out.println("Week "+(week+1)+ "= "+ total);
                total=0.0;
            }
```

Comment: It's `a += b` (`a = a + b`), not `a =+b` (see your second loop). Consider what the calls are doing, at the moment you're manipulating `counter` for multiple things, making it somewhat meaningless.

Comment: I see, so how should I use the counter more effectively for this? (since there are 4 rows, I need the sum for each column \

Comment: I would personally not use arrays for this (preferring OOP instead), but you could simply keep an array of the values you're wanting to track or even just more variables (one for each column). But for summing individual `z` data for each `x` and `y` in `[x][y][z]` respectively, you use the loops to define your "index variables": e.g. from 0 to the length of `calls` for x, and 0 to the length of `calls[x]` for y, etc. Then inside all those loops, you can read data like `int[] data = calls[x][y];` or `int value = calls[x][y][z]`. I'd read up more on loops and arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to calculate the sum of all elements in a week, you could simply change your second loop to:

```
for (int week = 0; week < calls.length; week++) {
        for (int days = 0; days < calls[week].length; days++) {
            for (int resp = 0; resp < calls[week][days].length; resp++) {
                total += (calls[week][days][resp]);
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Week " + (week + 1) + "= " + total);
        total = 0.0;
    }
```

which will print you total of each week. Here is an output:

```
Week 1= 14452.0
Week 2= 12148.0
Week 3= 11827.0
Week 4= 12368.0
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks you're a genius! Ive been struggling for 30 mins.

Comment: hmmm, so if I wanted to get the average for the weeks I would divide the total by 28 right?

Comment: If you would like to have an average for only a single week you would divide by 7. Or do you want to have the total average?

Comment: average, week by week (since there's 3 services, 7 days I would assume--divide by 28